# Host not served (ejabberd)

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I'm using out of the box [ejabberd/ecs - Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/ejabberd/ecs) and I've tried to run `curl` command (from my own container) to register the user , yet got following message:

> ```
> Host not served
> ```

actual `curl` command w/ output:

```
/app # curl -ks --request POST https://ejabberd:5443/api/register --data '{"user":"test","host":"localhost","password":"testing"}'
Host not served
/app #
```

As far as Docker goes, both my `app` and `ejabberd` containers are both in same network.

Please advise.

---

[ejabberd.yml](https://pastebin.com/waC6xtrg) just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to address my issue by adding container name as my `hosts`:

```
# grep -A2 hosts ./home/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml 
hosts:
  - localhost
  - ejabberd
#
```